# EMR 6 Beta with Docker Support has S3 Access Issue

Tags: docker, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am exploring the new EMR 6.0.0 with Docker support in order to make decision if we want to use it. One of our projects is written in Scala 2.11. But EMR 6.0.0 comes with Spark built from Scala 2.12. So I switched to try 6.00-beta, which is Spark 2.4.3 built from Scala 2.11. If it works on 6.0.0-beta, then we will upgrade our code to Scala 2.12 and use 6.0.0.

A few issues I am having are when I tried to run my Scala spark job:

1. When it tried to read parquet from S3, I got error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create temp dirs: [/mnt/s3]
2. When I tried to make API call with https, I got error: usun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
3. When it tried to read files from S3, I got error: Class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found. I was able to able to hack this one by passing the path by --jars. Maybe not the best solution.

I am guessing there must be something I need to set either during bootstrap or in the Docker file.

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the S3 issue. In beta version, /mnt/s3 is not mounted and given the read and write permission.

So I need to add the "docker.allowed.rw-mounts" to the container-executor configuration like below:

docker.allowed.rw-mounts=/etc/passwd,/mnt/s3

Comment: I've been wrestling with the same issue. I was hoping you could answer the following questions for me: (1) why did you include `/etc/passwd` to the list? (2) Did you add this extra config to the JSON file as `"docker.allowed.rw-mounts": "/etc/passwd,/mnt/s3"`? (3) I have errors with multiple mount points `/mnt/s3`, `/mnt1/s3`, `/mnt2/s3`, `/mnt3/s3`. So I added the extra config `"docker.allowed.rw-mounts": "/etc/passwd,/mnt/s3,/mnt1/s3,/mnt2/s3,/mnt3/s3"` and ended up with the error `Invalid docker read-write mount`. Any suggestions as to how this could be made to work?